# Sub activity Returning NULL intent object

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, ibm-mobilefirst

When trying to pass data from one activity to another it works fine in one direction parent>>child. But the return path child>>parent returns NULL intent object. I am trying from tomorrow and went through many answers, but couldn't make it work. Please help me out.

Main Activity Config File:

```
<activity android:name="com.abc.OpenExternalApplication" android:label="@string/title_activity_view_document"></activity>
```

Here is where I launch the activity from my Home activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String appURI = getIntent().getStringExtra("appURI");

        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appURI);

        startActivityForResult(intent, SUCCESS_CALLBACK );

}
```

Here is the child activity which passes control back to main activity :

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.equals(searchPolBtn)) {

        String polNo = polNoEditText.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), polNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent resultIntent = getIntent();
        // TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

        resultIntent.putExtra("data", polNo);

        this.finish();
    }
}
```

And Here is the parent activity which waits for result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(data!=null)
            LOGGER.warning(data.getStringExtra("data"));
        else
            LOGGER.warning("Data Is Null");

        this.finish();

}
```

And the output i am getting is Data is null.

An Error I am getting is : Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result.

Comment: Instead of `Intent resultIntent = getIntent();` why don't you use `Intent resultIntent = new Intent();`

Comment: I tried to use new Intent(), but no result for that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void onClick(View v) 
   {

    if(v.equals(searchPolBtn)) {

    String polNo = polNoEditText.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), polNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent resultIntent = getIntent();
    // TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.

     resultIntent.putExtra("data", polNo);

    setResult(1, resultIntent);



    this.finish();
   }
 }




protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
   if (requestCode == SUCCESS_CALLBACK && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) 
     {

  }
 }//onActivityResult
```

Comment: what is value of SUCCESS_CALLBACK

Comment: value of SUCCESS_CALLBACK is 1.

Comment: resultCode ==  RESULT_OK returns false.

Comment: Post Full Code Not Big Issue I will Slove But Post All Code and Xml

Comment: @user2173681 I have edited this answer. Please try again. The edit is: `setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);`

Answer (score 0):

First is there a reason not using:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
```

Then first put the result and then setResult (in this order)

```
resultIntent.putExtra("data", polNo);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

if it does not change anything try this afterwards:

```
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

Then you should check your requestCode in onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == SUCCESS_CALLBACK){
        if(data!=null)
            LOGGER.warning(data.getStringExtra("data"));
        else
            LOGGER.warning("Data Is Null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not declare a variable on your Parent activity and use that variable on your child activity to store value?

Comment: I am working on two different applications. Does it work in that scenario?